# Is there an alternative for ShouldSerialize[PropertyName] in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have been writing a lot of code lately which involves serialization using Json.NET and due to the nature of the data that I serialize, sometimes not all of their properties need to be serialized so, I do as follows...

```
public int Foo { get; set; }

public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() => Foo > -1;
```

This's good and works but involves a lot of work if you have many properties (***in my case I have over 100***).

So, I wanted to know if there's an alternative to writing those methods.

Comment: @DavidG bad dup, IMO; this is about conditional serialization, not ignoring a property

Comment: @MarcGravell You're right, didn't realise it was conditional

Comment: Are the rules the same for each property type? If so, you could create a custom formatter that only serializes if values of numeric properties are greater than -1, for example.

Comment: btw: there *is another* alternative to `ShouldSerialize*` - there's also `*Specified`, i.e. `public bool FooSpecified => Foo > -1;` - which doesn't gain you much :)

Comment: oh, that's interesting, I never knew that I could do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative option is to specific a `[DefaultValue(...)]` and use the `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` feature:

```
[DefaultValue(-1), JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int Foo { get; set; } = -1;
```

Note that it is important to initialize the value to the default value - hence the `= -1;` in the property initializer.

Comment: But then the OP still has to set a default value for, and apply an attribute to hundreds of properties, which they're trying to prevent.

Comment: @CodeCaster one way or another, OP is going to have to somehow let the library know which values to ignore, so one way or another there's going to have to be that value per property. Whether the OP thinks this is cleaner is a subjective question for the OP :) But: by the time you have hundreds of properties, maybe codegen is worth a look.